# How to evaluate simple expressions

Tags: mongodb

When developing complex aggregations, I want the ability to test out simpler expressions as a sanity check.  So I'm wondering if mongo shell has the ability to evaluate simple expressions.

For example, I want to do simple things like:

```
> { $hour: ISODate("2016-01-01T12:30:00Z") }
ISODate("2016-01-01T12:30:00Z")
```

In the example above it seems the shell isn't evaluating and returning the hour component as desired.

Is it possible to do what I want here?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use something other than Mongo Shell, [NoSQLBooster](https://nosqlbooster.com/compareEditions) will evaluate partial query operations. Just highlight the relevant section and click **Run**.

This is particularly useful for constructing pipelines with multiple stages. You can evaluate your pipeline one stage a time to verify which documents are passed to the next stage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but you can something like this:

```
var exprr = { "$hour": ISODate("2016-01-01T12:30:00Z") };

var tempCollection = "tempCollection";
db.getCollection(tempCollection).insert({});
db.getCollection(tempCollection).aggregate([
    {"$project" : {"_id" : 0, "result" : exprr}} 
]);
db.getCollection(tempCollection).drop();
```

Or you can wrap last part in a function and save it, for resue. The idea is we will make a temporary collection, insert a blank document on it and evaluate an expression the aggregation way. The downside is you can only evaluate those expressions which are supported in project aggregation operation.